# google seller ratings - Sending content from multiple clients

Tags: php, google-api, rating-system, google-api-php-client, merchant-account

I'm working on a freemium ratings and review plugin which clients will sign up to use. The idea is that the client (lets refer to them as Supplier A) will sign up and integrate their e-commerce site with our API. When an order is created SupplierA's system will send our API the details and we will store them, a few days later we will request by email the customer write a review of the company and of the product. We store SupplierA's reviewss on our server and have several methods for SupplierA to retrieve them.

How do we integrate our product with google seller ratings, to allow us send SupplierA's product or company reviews and ratings to google, these reviews will then need to show on the clients Google Seller Ratings account and in the google search results for SupplierA.

Idealy we're looking at sending product and company reviews to google on behalf of our clients, overall making it easier for them. Where do I look for the correct API calls, any examples of similar uses, code repositories, How can I work with multiple client accounts?.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an agreement with Google to send them data for Seller Ratings, we've been trying to get this with Google for about 2 years with little luck as it's a guarded secret. The moment I learn more I'll update the answer, I know someone who has been able to get approved but he wasn't able to share much with me.